# Empty string in number formatting

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, casting

[This](http://img99.imageshack.us/img99/1398/assignment.jpg) is my assignment:

Here are my questions:

1. How can I fix this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
>           at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1012)
>           at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:527)
>           at extracredit.Main.readData(Main.java:72)
>           at extracredit.Main.main(Main.java:27)

2. Are there any other problems that you can see with this program?

Here's my code so far:

```
    import java.io.*;
            import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
            import java.util.*;
            import java.util.StringTokenizer;

            public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     String fname = "data.txt"; //Read in the data file for use in the array
     String pass= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the " +
             "password to continue:"); /*Have the user enter the password to 
     access the file. */

     checkPass(pass); // Verify that the password is correct before continuing.
     readData (fname); // Read data, print output and save output file.

  }


    private static void checkPass (String pass)
    {
     String password= "INF260";
     int passCount= 0;   
       if (pass.equals(password)) {
         System.out.println("The password is correct. Continuing...");
       }
       else {
        do {
           pass= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please re-enter the" +
                   "password:");
           passCount++;
        } while (!pass.equals(password) && passCount < 2);
           if (!pass.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("You have tried to enter the " +
                   "password too many times. Exiting...");
            System.exit(0);
           }
           else {
               System.out.println("The password is correct. Continuing...");
           }
       }
    }
       public static void readData (String data) throws IOException{           
            FileReader inputData= new FileReader (data);
            BufferedReader findNum= new BufferedReader (inputData);
            String str= findNum.readLine ();

            int count=-1;
            int countNum= 0; 
            double total= 0;
            double min= 0;
            double max= 0;
            double average= 0;

            FileWriter writeFile = new FileWriter("sales.txt");
            PrintWriter printFile = new PrintWriter(writeFile);

            while (str != null)
             {
             double num= Double.parseDouble (str);
             if (count == 0){
               countNum++; // counter of Reciepts to use
              }
            str = findNum.readLine();
        }
           double [][] input = new double [countNum][10];
            total= getCurrentTotal(input); /*This will get the total 
             from the method getCurrentTotal.*/
            min= getCurrentMin(input); /*This will get the minimum value from
            the method getCurrentMin.*/
            max= getCurrentMax (input);  /*This will get the maximum value from
            the method getCurrentMax.*/

            average= (total / countNum);   //Calculate the average.     
            System.out.println("The List of Today's Sales:");
                for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++){
                    System.out.println ();
                    System.out.println("Customer " + row + "\t");
                    for (int column = 0; column < input[row].length; column++){
                       if (input [row].length < 10){        
                        System.out.println(input[row][column] + "\t");
                        str = findNum.readLine();
                    }              
                    else{ 
                        System.out.println ("There are too many receipts" +
                                " for one Customer.\n");
                        System.exit (0);
                    }
                }

            }

    System.out.println ("There are " + countNum + "receipts in the list."); 
        /*This will print the total of receipts in the list.*/                      
    System.out.println ("The total of today's sales is $" + total); /*
        This will print the total of the sales for the day.*/
    System.out.println ("The average of today's sales is $" + average); /*  
        This will print the average sale total.*/
    System.out.println ("The highest receipt is $" + max); /* This will print 
         the highest sale.*/
    System.out.println ("The lowest receipt is $" + min); /* This will print 
        the lowest sale.*/
    Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println ("\n The current time is:" + date.toString()); /* This 
         will print the current date and time */

       }



    public static double getCurrentTotal (double [][] input){
        double totalAmount = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < input [row].length; column++){
                totalAmount += input [row][column];
            }
        }
        return totalAmount;    
    }

    public static double getCurrentMin (double [][] input) {    
        double currentMin = input[0][0]; 
        for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < input [row].length; column++){
                if (currentMin > input[row][column])
                    currentMin = input[row][column];
                }    
        }
        return currentMin;
    }

    public static double getCurrentMax (double [][] input){    
        double currentMax = input[0][0];
        for (int row = 0; row < input.length; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column < input [row].length; column++){
                if (currentMax < input[row][column]){
                    currentMax = input[row][column];
                }
            }    
        }
        return currentMax;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to use Stack Overflow to get this much specialized help on your assignment. Talk to a TA and study on your own if you're struggling with a class, then turn to Stack Overflow for help with narrow issues you have put time into but can't figure out.

Comment: I don't have any problems in my class, this is just an extra credit assignment. My professor actually recommend our class to this website. I posted the code I have already written because I'm not just asking for answers and I genuinely want help working out these problems. This is just a very basic beginning programming class, we have not yet learned how to do some of the things presented above. I just thought it would be better to study with the help of better programmers than myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// from your main method
String fname = "data.txt";
readData (fname);

// the method being called
public static void readData (String data[][]){           
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(data));
```

We have an incompatibility here.

- fname is a String
- The method takes a String[] as a parameter.
- the constructor newFileReader() takes a string, not 2d array.

All of these three should be the same data type.

> How can I separate each "receipt" with zero (like shown in the image link above)?

You don't have to.  You have to READ from that file with the zeros in it.
I would recommend you write a method something like this:

public double[] readOneReceipt(BufferedReader reader);

This method should

- Read line by line until it encounters a 0 entry
- for each entry it reads convert the value into a number (double?)
- Store the number in a temporary structure.
- When you encounter the "0", create a new array of the correct size and copy the read values into it.

> How can I write the output into a separate file?

With a java.io.FileWriter

The hardest bit of this IMO is the fact that you are told to store the data in a 2d array, but you don't exactly what size to make the array until you've read the data.
Which means that you either use a temporary dynamic structure, or read the file twice - once to find out how many receipts there are so that you can make the array, and then again to actually read the receipt data.

Comment: Thanks for your help evnafets, I'm working on fixing it right now. 
-Ava

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is:

- study your course material
- start with a subset of the problem like just reading the file.
- test it
- loop over:

  - continue to improve and enhance the program until it fulfills all the requirements.
  - test it
- hand it in